# ddev start - shows operation not permitted

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, chmod, ddev

Installed DDEV to use to run our local server.
On my local github repo folder, I run the following

```
$: ddev start
```

this shows the following error below:

```
Adding custom/shell commands failed: Failed to chmod file /mnt/d/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/.ddev/.global_commands/.gitattributes to mode -rwxr-xr-x, err=chmod /mnt/d/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/.ddev/.global_commands/.gitattributes: operation not permitted
Starting sunrise...
Failed to start sunrise: chmod /mnt/d/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/.ddev/.homeadditions/README.txt: operation not permitted
```

Any idea how to fix it?

I tried the following:

```
sudo chmod -rwxr-xr-x /mnt/d/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/.ddev/.homeadditions/README.txt
```

But no luck.

Thanks to whom can help.

Comment: Are you perhaps using Docker Desktop with the experimental settings turned on (like Virtiofs)? If so, please turn it off. But you tag this with "linux". Please do a `ddev debug test` and put the results in a gist on gist.github.com so I know your environment. The thing that you'd want to change the permissions on would be your project `.ddev/.homeadditions` directory. take a look at that. (I don't think I've seen this before; if I were you I'd remove your .ddev folder and start over again.)

Comment: Please try out the troubleshooting steps, step-by-step in https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/troubleshooting/ - Turning off firewall is one of them. If you're using the new Docker Desktop for Linux... don't. Switch back to traditional docker engine install.